# how to display python console output on html page using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

```
def execute():
    print("this is imam")
    #perform some task after first print then print next function
    print('this akarsh')
    #perform some task after first print then print next function
    print('this is abhi')

@app.route('/')
def home ():
    return render_template('index.html', x= execute())
```

> I just wanted to print the upper three print statements on my html page i have tried with the set variable to pass, please help me with this. As it prints on python console one after the other performing certain task as mentioned.

Comment: why not pass these sentences to `x` directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
def execute():
    return """
        this is imam
        this akarsh
        this is abhi
    """
```

Comment: after first print there is sum task, then the result of previous task is going to print in second print function like vise. so, it like i want to display on html page as it appears on python console while running one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `index.html` as a template. It should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>This is a parameter from app</h3>
    {{ x }}
</body>
</html>
```

and you have to change your `execute()` function like this:

```
def execute():
    x = 'this is imam'
    print("this is imam")
    #perform some task after first print then print next function
    y = 'this akarsh'
    print('this akarsh')
    #perform some task after first print then print next function
    z = 'this is abhi'
    print('this is abhi')
    result = [x,y,x]
    return result
```

You can use a list (or any python data structure)  to return your results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

1. create `Outposts` class

   ```
   class Outpost:
       def __init__(self):
           self.outposts = []

       def add_outpost(self, data):
           self.outposts.append(data)
   ```
2. make a copy of Outposts for `execute()` function and run `execute()`:

   ```
   execute_outposts = Outpost()
   execute()
   ```
3. in execute function replace the print with `execute_outposts.add_outpost(text)`
4. and put `execute_outposts.outposts` in `x`